# How can I set a Url in a webview if I have many buttons with different Urls?

Tags: android, button, webview

For example if I have 3 buttons and I want to use this buttons to redirect to different urls without use many webviews but only one webview.

```
button1 = http://example.com
button2 = http://stackoverflow.com
button3 = http://android.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the click of each `Button`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, THE_ACTIVITY_THAT_HOLDS_WEBVIEW.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Change the URL that has to be passed to the `WebView` depending on the `Button` clicked.

In the `Activity` that holds the `WebView`:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(this.getIntent().getDataString());
```

Adapt the code if you are doing things a little differently.

Comment: Thanks @Siddhart Lele it's what i wanted.

Comment: @JesúsVélez: Glad to have helped. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use **HashMap** with **Integer, String key values pair**,

```
Like Map<Integer,String> webUrls = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

Now store button's id as key and url as Values.

```
webUrls.put(button1.getId(),"http://facebook.com");
```

And load like, in `onClick()` of Button

```
String url = webUrls.get(view.getId());
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Now, you don't have to write onClick for every Buttons. Just in onClick() you can get Url from HashMap.